# Codeigniter Image Uploading not working online

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

I have an application that neede photo upload, have done it in codeigniter, works perect on localhost, but it is not working online.

**VIEW PAGE CODE :**

```
<div> 
                  <form id="uploadimage" method="POST" name="uploadimage" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>onebachhpan/savephoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" accept="image/*" /><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" class="button_example" id="upload_button" name="upload_button" value="Upload"/>
             </form>
             <br/>
             <form  id="removeimage" method="POST" name="removeimage" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>onebachhpan/removephoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 64px; " class="button_example" id="delete_button" name="delete_button" value="Delete"/>
             </form>
             </div>
```

Following is the controller code for image upload:
This is working fine on localhost:

**CONTROLLER CODE:**

```
function savephoto()
    {
         $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['upload_path'] = './profilepic/'; //location to store image
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
         redirect(base_url().'uploaderror');


        }
        else
        {
            $photo = $this->upload->data();
            $data['photo'] = $photo;    
            $id = $this->session->userdata('MemberId');
            $filename = $photo['file_name'];
            $extension = $photo['file_ext'];

            $this->load->model('profile_model');
            $this->profile_model->photo($extension,$id);



          // echo "<pre>";print_r($photo);
            $newpath = './profilepic/'.$id.$extension;

            $config['source_image'] = './profilepic/'.$filename;
            $config['overwrite']=true;

            $config['new_image'] = $newpath;

            $config['width']  = '170';
            $config['height']  = '240';
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;


            //$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            unlink('./profilepic/'.$filename);
            //$this->load->view('onebachhpan_index');
            redirect(base_url().'profile');

        }   
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? What is the value of $_FILES in the controller? Have you turned on error reporting to see what is going wrong?

Comment: I m uploading a single file, hence i dn't require $_FILES, also the above code is working perfect on the localhost, but when i deployed it to online server photouploading is not working...you can check at [link](http://one.bachhpan.org/)

Comment: If you upload a single file or multiple files, the data is sent to PHP's `$_FILES` variable. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Set permissions of uploading folder to `777`, check php configured max size for uploading files and make sure the same extensions and so on are enabled in server as in local.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Array
(
    [error] => 

The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

)

Comment: @mcryan,@robin,@raheel,@MDeSilva **thanks all** for helping out, actually there is a problem in codeigniter/system/libraries/upload.php : Line ::1058 ::: > @exec('file --brief --mime-type ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_path']), $output, $return_code);  -----changed to ---> @exec('file --brief --mime-type ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']), $output, $return_code);

Answer (score 0):

Try out this example, it works perfectly

```
 //File name
$cat_image_name = $_FILES["cat_image"]["name"] ;

$date_added = strtotime(date("m/d/Y H:i:s"));


//File uploading params 
$config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/categories';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['file_name'] = $date_added."_ipad";
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

//Loading Library - File Uploading
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//Upload the image
if (!empty($cat_image_name)) 
{
        $this->upload->do_upload('cat_image');
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $category_image_ipad = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $img_extension = $data['upload_data']['file_ext'];
}
```